# eCharts 5 Axis Label Overlap

Tags: reactjs, echarts

[image]

I recently upgraded echarts from 4.7.0 to 5.0.0 and noticed that now the x axis labels are overlapping. I've looked through the docs but can't seem to find an option that would resolve this.

The option configuration I have it pretty simple:

gridIndex: ndx,
type: "time",
splitLine: {
show: true
}

Would appreciate any help with this!

Answer (score 11):

I solved with this option:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'time',
  axisLabel: {
    hideOverlap: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted -- the hideOverlap property solved a very similar issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

you check this options
`series: { type: time, labelLayout: { hideoverlap = true } }`

Comment: tried your solution but it doesn't seem to hide the overlap for the x axis labels

Comment: series: { type: time, labelLayout: { hideOverlap = true } }   - working but need to correct case